# How to delete element ONLY from new list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let suppose I have a list `l` and I make new list `temp` from `l`. When I try to delete element from `temp` it also deletes element from `l` too. This is so strange. How can I only delete element from `temp`?

```
l = [1,2,3]
temp = l
temp.remove(3)
print(l, temp)
Output: ([1, 2], [1, 2])
```

Comment: you need to copy a list, because l and temp refer to the same list

Comment: Check [this blog](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html#h_assignment) to understand the reason for this behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually both `l` and `temp` are names that refer to the same object `list` in memory. When you do something with any of them, you are doing it to the underlying object list that is pointed by those two names.
You can always create a new object by using the copy method:

```
temp = l.copy()
```

And that way, you will be having two names pointing to different objects.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a list using `temp=l`, python doesn't create new object.
It refers to the same object as `temp` so whatever changes you make will reflect in original list as well. Use `copy` method to avoid this

```
l = [1,2,3]
temp = l.copy()
temp.remove(3)
print(l, temp)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3] [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do this:

```
l = [1,2,3]
temp = l
```

You haven't created a new list, but instead you have merely created a new reference to the same list.  Changing the list through either variable changes it for both.

To copy the list, you can do:

```
temp = list(l)
```

Another way is to do `temp = l[:]`, which is equivalent.  In Python 3 you can also do `temp = l.copy()`, but that won't work in Python 2.

Then you can change either list without affecting the other.

Answer (score 0):

`temp = l` is simply assigning `temp` to a *reference* of `l`. So whatever you do to one list, the other is affected.

We can check this with the [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) function:

```
print(id(l))
# 1739514774400

print(id(temp))
# 1739514774400
```

Which returns the *same* unique address for each object in memory.

We can see this in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id):

> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value.
>
> CPython implementation detail: This is the address of the object in memory.

In this case both `l` and `temp` are the same, so they have the same *identities*.

We can fix this by assigning a *copy* instead:

```
l = [1,2,3]
temp = l[:]
```

Which now gives different identities and only removes `2` from `temp`:

```
print(id(l))
# 1822815159168

print(id(temp))
# 1822815159104

temp.remove(3)

print(l, temp)
# [1, 2, 3] [1, 2]
```